C program for radix-sorting real numbers doesn't sort the numbers properly
I made a C program that is supposed to get a series of real numbers (including floating points and negative numbers) from a user input to sort them using a radix sort function, but it doesn't work properly with the negative numbers, as while the positive numbers are properly sorted, the negative numbers are put after the positive numbers and are in the wrong order (see example below).
Here is the code I used:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX 100

void radix_sort(uint32_t A[], unsigned int n) {
        uint32_t bucket0[MAX], bucket1[MAX];
        unsigned int mask, count0, count1;
        for(int d = 0; d <= 31; d++) {
                mask = 1U << d;
                count0 = count1 = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        if((A[i] & mask) == 0) {
                                bucket0[count0++] = A[i];
                        } else {
                                bucket1[count1++] = A[i];
                        }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < count0; i++) {
                        A[i] = bucket0[i];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
                        A[count0 + i] = bucket1[i];
                }
        }
}

int main() {
        unsigned int n;

        printf("Enter a number of integers not greater than 100: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);

        if (n <= 0 || n > MAX) {
                printf("Invalid input.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        float float_numbers[MAX];
        printf("Enter %d real numbers:\n", n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                scanf("%f", &float_numbers[i]);
        }

        printf("Before sorting:\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%.3f\n", float_numbers[i]);
        }

        uint32_t A[MAX];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                A[i] = *(uint32_t*)&float_numbers[i];
        }

        radix_sort(A, n);

        printf("After sorting:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                printf("%.3f\n", *(float*)&A[i]);
        }
}

I expected this to happen:
Enter a number of integers not greater than 100: 5
Enter 5 real numbers:
3.6
-1.4
0.6
-5.8
0.5
Before sorting:
3.600
-1.400
0.600
-5.800
0.500
After sorting:
-5.800
-1.400
0.500
0.600
3.600

And here is what actually happens:
Enter a number of integers not greater than 100: 5
Enter 5 real numbers:
3.6
-1.4
0.6
-5.8
0.5
Before sorting:
3.600
-1.400
0.600
-5.800
0.500
After sorting:
0.500
0.600
3.600
-1.400
-5.800

Can you find a way to fix this problem?

In what sequence do you expect unsigned integers, some which had negative values, to be sorted?

Time to use your debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what really happens.

With integers, negative values have the highest bit set so they are larger than any positive number.  You will need to cater for them separately.

A[i] = *(uint32_t*)&float_numbers[i]... Why? That breaks strict aliasing.

if (n <= 0 || n > MAX) { This will allow out-of-bounds-accesses. If n==MAX as the arrays only have entries 0..MAX-100.

IEEE 754 binary32 float has a sign-and-magnitude representation, so when mapped to uint32_t values, the values need to be manipulated to sort in the correct order. Try replacing if ((A[i] & mask) == 0) { with uint32_t a = A[i]; if ((a & (1U << 31)) != 0) { a = -a; } else { a |= (1U << 31); } if ((a & mask) == 0) {. Store the original A[i] value in the bucket, not the manipulated a value.

@rcgldr No, that would sort the negative numbers in decreasing order, followed by the non-negative numbers in increasing order. (Hint: sign-and-magnitude, not 2's complement.) However, I think my replacement fails to sort -0.0 correctly.

My previous attempt incorrectly sorted -0.0 after 0.0. To fix it, replace a = -a; with a = ~a;, i.e. replace if ((A[i] & mask) == 0) { with uint32_t a = A[i]; if ((a & (1U << 31)) != 0) { a = ~a; } else { a |= (1U << 31); } if ((a & mask) == 0) {.

@IanAbbott -  for a non-conditional conversion: convert float to uint32_t before radix sort: a[i] ^= ((uint32_t)((int32_t)( a[i])>>31)>>1)|0x80000000ul; . Convert back to float after radix sort: a[i] ^= ((uint32_t)((int32_t)(~a[i])>>31)>>1)|0x80000000ul; .  Note that this treats -0.0 as less than +0.0.
